# Scroll Horizontal

Tags: jquery, scroll, slider

Muchachos tengo esta duda. Tengo un jquery que me funciona bien en un mac, pero en windows me da problemas.

Para dejar en contexto... Tengo un scroll horizontal que cuando hago scroll va pasando imagenes y todo, una vez que termina permite ir bajando dentro del sitio, pero no es así cuando me topo verlo en un pc windows, este no toma bien el scroll y solamente baja.

Mi pregunta es que si puedo dejar que mi slider horizontal pueda funcionar bien en los dos tipo de pc?

Acá dejo el script:

```
var cDataIndex = 1; // first page index
var maxIndex = document.querySelectorAll('.contenedor').length; // max index
var isOnScrolling = false;

var fnGoTo = function(goToPrev){
  if((goToPrev && cDataIndex <= 1) || (!goToPrev && cDataIndex >= maxIndex)) return; // there isn't another container

  isOnScrolling = true;

  document.querySelector('[data-index="' + cDataIndex + '"]').classList = 'contenedor animated ' + (!goToPrev ? 'slideOutLeft' : 'slideOutRight');

  cDataIndex += goToPrev ? -1 : 1;

  document.querySelector('[data-index="' + cDataIndex + '"]').classList = 'contenedor main animated ' + (goToPrev ? 'slideInLeft' : 'slideInRight'); // hide current container

  setTimeout(function(){
    isOnScrolling = false;
  }, 1000)
}

var MouseWheelHandler = function(e){
  if(!isOnScrolling) {
    fnGoTo(e.wheelDelta > 0);
  }
}

//bind mouse wheel event
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", MouseWheelHandler, false);
//  FIN SCRIPT SLIDER VERTICAL
```

Sería de gran ayuda su aporte muchachos.Gracias!